# How to parse odd numbered fields from a flat file in unix?

Tags: unix, awk

I have a flat file and I want to parse odd numbered columns out of it from all the rows.

I am quite new to UNIX and the way I approached is this

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS = OFS = "|" } { for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) { if(i%2==0) { print $i }}}' newProcessFile.txt
```

Obviously it is not producing the required output. 
What am I doing wrong ? Please explain .

Comment: for odd cols, shouldn't it be i%2!=0 ?

Comment: Ah my bad !! Sorry for this horrible mistake !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this `awk`

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) printf "%s ",$i;print ""}' file
```

It will print every second columns.

```
cat file
one
one two
one two three
one two three four
one two three four five
one two three four five six
```

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) printf "%s ",$i;print ""}' file
one
one
one three
one three
one three five
one three five
```

---

With other separators:

```
cat file
one
one|two
one|two|three
one|two|three|four
one|two|three|four|five
one|two|three|four|five|six
```

```
awk -F\| '{s="";for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) {s=s?s FS $i:$i} print s}' file
one
one
one|three
one|three
one|three|five
one|three|five
```

Comment: Great one !! Just one question without ;print"" it is not producing the desired output. I mean if I write
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "|" } { for ( i = 1 ; i <= NF ; i+=2 ) printf "%s" , $i }' newProcessFile.txt
it is not displaying the desired output.
Why is it so ??

Comment: @user3655102 If you have other separators, you need to change it some, like this: `awk -F\| '{s="";for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) {s=s?s FS $i:$i} print s}' file`  It will then not print every data, but make a variable, then print it. The `print ""` was used to get a new line.

Comment: +1 but this will add a trailing blank char to the end of every output line. The correct way to loop printing fields is `for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) printf "%s%s",(i>1?OFS:""),$i; print ""` or if you knew you'd enter the loop when i==NF (not this case): `for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) printf "%s%s",$i,(i<NF?OFS:ORS)` with no need for a subsequent `print ""`.

Comment: @EdMorton If you use my second solution  it will not give blanks after the line if space is is separator :)

Comment: Yeah but it will delete all leading fields that have numeric value zero or are empty (which seems to be a common thread these days ;-) ). It'd also be slower than the one that just prints the fields as you go along due to the repeated string concatenation (a very slow operation in awk due to dynamic memory allocation), but thats nbd. It will probably produce syntax errors on some awks due to the unparenthesized ternary expression too.

Comment: @EdMorton Uffff the `0` is always making trouble.  What about this? `awk -F\| '{s="";for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) {s=(s?s FS:"")$i};print s}' file`.  It handles `0` in first row, at least in my test.

Comment: @Jotne Sorry for the trouble .. but  {s=s?s FS $i:$i} print s}' in your second approach , what does it do ? How does it print ? s= s?s 
FS $i:$i how this is working I am not getting that ? 
I am new to unix but this special operators I do not know ,, Can you please explain a bit

Comment: @user3655102 Question about the `0` what to `Ed` :)