# How to print odd numbered fields from a text file using awk in Unix?

Tags: unix, awk, printf

I have posted the same question before but as i just a beginner in Unix I am unable to understand the answer given to it though certainly that helps to fulfill my requirement.

```
awk -F\| '{s="";for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) {s=s?s FS $i:$i} print s}' file
```

What does this {s=s?s FS $i:$i} print s} do ? How does it print the required output ? I am unable to understand . Is it kind of special operator in Unix that prints without the usage of print or printf statements ? 
Please explain . Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It is a ternary operator

Comment: Yes but how does it evaluate the expression and print it ?
Could you please explain

Comment: PS this is related to my answer her: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795963/how-to-parse-odd-numbered-fields-from-a-flat-file-in-unix/26796059#26796059

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`? :` is the ternary operator provided by awk

**syntax**

`expression ? value 1 : value 2`

if the expression evaluates true, then the value of the ternary expression is `value1` else `value2`

eg assume `var =1`

`output=var==1 ? 10 : 5;`

here since `var==1` evaluates true, the value of ternary operator is `10` hence `output` becomes `10`

Now **What `{s=s?s FS $i:$i} print s}` do**

- `s ?` evaluates true when `s` is not empty. That is when it is not processing the first colum. It sets `s FS $i` that is `s` seperated by `FS` seperated by `$i`
- when it evaluates false, that is `s==""` it sets `s` as the first column `$i`.

This ensures that the fiels seprator `|` is only added **before every column other than the first column**

To understand little bit further consider a file

```
$ cat input
one|two|three|four|five|six
$ awk -F\| '{s="";for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) { {s=s?s FS $i:$i} print s }}' input
```

here the `print s` works for each iteration of the `for` loop giving output

```
one                   <= s="", evaluates false, hence no FS, | added to column
one|three             <= s=one, evaluates true, hence FS, | added to column and so on 
one|three|five
```

Comment: Awesome explanation . Thanks for the much needed help.

Comment: @user3655102 just see the modified awk script. i have broken down the output and how its formed. Hope its clear now :)

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F\| '{s="";for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) {s=s?s FS $i:$i} print s}' file
```

1) -F\| => field seperator is set to | (escaping required, hence \|)

2) s="" => an empty string

3) for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) =>
NF stands for number of fields in the current record being processed. For loop to go from 1st field to last, skipping the odd fields (not i+=2)

4) s=s?s FS $i:$i => 
This checks if s is equal to s.if yes, then it will append the ith field to s (s FS $i). if no,  then it will copy ith field to s ($i). This is not really required, it can be s = s FS $i

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt and detailed help .

Answer (score 1):

It may be more clear if we reformat your awk code:

```
{
  s = "";
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; i += 2)
  {
    s = s ? s FS $i : $i
  }
  print s
}
```

First we have a loop over all odd numbers from 1 to NF inclusive.  Inside that, we build a string `s`.  Each loop iteration, if `s` is not empty we append `FS $i`; if it was empty we simply assign `$i`.  The net effect of all this is to make `s` contain the text from all the odd-number fields, separated by `FS`.  Finally, we print `s`.

A more concise form, without the ternary, would be:

```
{
  s = $1;
  for (i = 3; i <= NF; i += 2)
  {
    s = s FS $i
  }
  print s
}
```

Comment: Superb man !! You made my day . Thanks for further breaking it down .